# Reduce Redundancy Of CASE Expresion SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case, redundancy

Here is my SQL Server query

```
SELECT
CASE(
    SELECT POPULATION
    FROM MEXICO
) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE
    SELECT POPULATION
    FROM MEXICO
END
```

I need to make a query return 1 if it's value is equal to 0, is there a way to do it without repeating the SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
select case population
         when 0 then 1
         else population
       end
from mexico;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83f9c0e53b767d80dfbd75c1377def3e)